# Reassignment replicas don`t match the list of replicas for Reassignment for partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have `6` kafka brokers in our  cluster

Brokers ids are - `1121 - 1126`

We try to reassingmnet the first partition of topic - `data-topic`

The first partition is - `data-topic-0`

But after  Reassignment  , and when  we run the verification as

```
kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper zoo01:2181 --reassignment-json-file /tmp/file-partition.json --verify
```

We get

```
Reassignment replicas (1125,1124, 1126) don`t match the list of replicas for Reassignment (1125,1122,1123) for partition data-topic-0

Reassignment of partition data-topic-0 failed
```

**any idea why this happens?**

`note1` - Proposed partition reassignment configuration is in the file - `file-partition.json`

`note2` - We have `100` partitions of topic `data-topic`

Comment: Are you saying that the reassignment failed? Or that the verification failed?  If it's only the verification that failed, can you post the reassignment command you used? And any errors or messages that command returned?

Comment: only reassignment verification is failed ,

Comment: the errors are as I already mentioned 0 "eassignment replicas (1125,1124, 1126) don`t match the list of replicas for Reassignment (1125,1122,1123) for partition data-topic-0

Reassignment of partition data-topic-0 failed"

Comment: reassignment command - kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper zoo01:2181 --reassignment-json-file /tmp/file-partition.json --execute

Comment: I see also same isshue on the post - https://users.kafka.apache.narkive.com/CIi5ipTe/it-s-5-41am-we-re-after-20-hours-of-debugging-our-prod-cluster-see-notassignedreplicaexception-and

Comment: I think the JSON file used for reassignment lacks proper replica assignment. Can you share details of that file ? I just need to see whether the format is right and file is a valid json. Also never use even number of Kafka brokers. This affect ensemble operation and leader election.

Comment: regarding to kafka even number - can you provide documentation so I will share my colleges about it?

Comment: @CRU I think you mean Zookeeper servers...

Comment: It would help if you could show the JSON file and the topic description

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, you are right. I do mean zookeeper servers.

Comment: @jessica You can refer to answers mentioned in this post https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-actual-role-of-Zookeeper-in-Kafka-What-benefits-will-I-miss-out-on-if-I-don%E2%80%99t-use-Zookeeper-and-Kafka-together