# kafka + revived a partition LeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latest epoch

Tags: apache-kafka

on one of our kafka machines we see the following , from `server.log`

```
revived a partition LeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latest epoch 
This implies messages have arrived out of order
New epoch1, offset 24782988, current epoch2 offset 4049299988
```

we have kafka version - `1.x` , and we have `8 Kafka` servers in the cluster

but this issue happens only on the first Kafka in the cluster

what is the best solution for this behavior ?

Comment: the problem is that we cant do assignment partitions , you can look on my previous post in stack-overflow ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59826890/reassignment-replicas-dont-match-the-list-of-replicas-for-reassignment-for-part )

Comment: You need to show your json file and topic description. The error seems to suggest that you're trying to move replicas that don't exist (because they already moved, or you entered the wrong ID)